# Colorize output of a command using multiple "sed" calls

Tags: bash, sed, colors

i'd like to colorize the output of "history" with its timestamps. Let's say one line would be

```
2084  10.05.16 17:08:13 history | sed 's/^[ 0-9]*[ ]/\o033[1;32m&\o033[0m/' | tail -n10
```

Currently i figured

```
    history | sed 's/^[ 0-9]*[ ]/\o033[1;32m&\o033[0m/' | tail -n10
```

to print the counter in a yellowish tone. Now i'd like to have the timestamp in another color. I tried

```
    history | sed 's/[ 0-9.:]*[ ]/\o033[1;31m&\o033[0m/' | sed 's/^[ 0-9]*[ ]/\o033[1;32m&\o033[0m/' | tail -n10
```

but that displays the counter as well as the time stamp in red.

How do i have to write the sed calls to have "2084" in one color and the time stamp "10.05.16 17:13:39" in another?

THX in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`history` on the machine I use doesn't have a timestamp field but if your history command outputs lines like:

```
2084  10.05.16 17:08:13 history
```

then you'd want:

```
history | sed -E 's/^(\S+)(\s+)(\S+\s+\S+)/\o033[1;31m\1\o033[0m\2\o033[1;32m\3\o033[0m/'
```

The above uses GNU sed for `\S` and `\s` - replace them with `[^[:blank:]]` and `[[:blank:]]` respectively if your sed doesn't support them.

Comment: If you're using bash, you can add a timestamp to the output of `history` by setting the environment variable `HISTTIMEFORMAT` to a `strftime` format string.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend installing `grc` (a generic colouriser program) and creating a custom config file, like so:

```
# conf.history for grc
# sequence number
regexp=^\s+\d+
colours=yellow
=======
# date/time stamp
regexp=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+
colours=red
count=once
```

Then you can do this:

```
history | grcat conf.history
```

If I set `HISTTIMEFORMAT` to `"%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S"` to match your output, the above works on my machine - I get yellow sequence numbers and red date/time stamps and white everything else.

Comment: Does that just color the first match of the regexp on the line or every occurrence? I mean if I did `echo '05.10.2016 12:58:26'` then ran history I'd get `34439  05.10.2016 13:08:01 echo '05.10.2016 12:58:26'` so then would `history | grcat conf` color just the first timestamp that I do want colored or would it also color the 2nd one that I don't want colored?

Comment: Good point, @EdMorton. Adding `count=once` makes sure it only colorizes the first occurrence.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Please accept my answer if it solved your problem.:)